# Looking for users in Cisco configuration

Tags: regex, cisco

I need to get an expression to get users in cisco which has not lower privileges 0 or 1.
Users can be found in configuration file in the following way:

```
username myuser privilege 15 password 7 5345345345
```

So, I´m trying with expression:

```
(username.*privilege )(?!([01]))( password 7)
```

To get all lines with "username privilege" for any user name, followed by a group of characters that aren´t 0 or 1, and followed by "password" and other characters.

But testing in some online tester webpage i am not receiving the desired result.
what am i doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a word boundary after `[01]\b` and when that assertion is true, you could still have to match the digits using `[0-9]+`

The pattern matches password 7 literally, but you could also use `[0-9]+` here to match the digits.

```
.*\b(username.*privilege) (?![01]\b)[0-9]+ (password [0-9]+).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkbSN2/1)

Note that if you only want to match the whole line, you can omit the capture groups:

```
.*\busername.*?privilege (?![01]\b)[0-9]+ password [0-9].*
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is magical for me, it works. I have never used \b and i think after reading documentation i´ve understood it. What i am not sure to be clear is about [0-9]+ after negating lookahead

Comment: @AndresAguado That means that you can match one or more digits. The assertion before it checks that it can not be only 0 or 1

Comment: @AndresAguado Did it work out?

Comment: yes it works and i have understand it. thanks a lot for your help, very useful